# Feature engineering zero-inflated distributions for Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I am trying to fit a neural network on a set of various features. For most of the features I've followed some common rule of thumbs, so as to get nicely distributed features. Not so imbalanced binary features, standardizing continuous features, taking some logs to get closer to normal gaussian... and so on.

I am a bit stuck with zero inflated feature, that is features for which the distribution is nice overall excpet for a unique spike, generally in 0 ('zero inflation'). I mainly have two kinds of distributions: spike and slab (some gaussian + zero inflation) and what look like half gaussian + zero inflation. The latter seems to be interpretable as a compounded poisson process, where the zero are due to a lack of event.

I wonder if there is some trick or general rule of thumbs to deal with such features. My first idea was to build an indicator (or +1/-1) of the feature being zero or not. But I don't know what to do for the magnitude of the features.

Is there a good approach to deal with such features ?

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: Handling binary and non-inflated variables usually gives faster convergence and stavbility of the calibration process (different seeds giving the same result). I was wondering if there was a way to deal with zero-inflated values in a 'good' way.

Comment: I think in this case you should create two inputs: one which is a binary indicator of whether the feature is zero or not (as you suggest), and the other which is the feature normalized/standardized conditioned on it being nonzero